# establish_connection': database configuration specifies nonexistent mysql2 adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I changed my database from `sqlite3` to `mysql` after doing all the migrations. When I connect to the rails server an error occurs.

I tried all the solutions I could find but none works. When I try to run the server with `rails server` I get:

```
> establish_connection': database configuration specifies nonexistent
> mysql2 adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound)
```

I am new to rails I dont know what causes this. May be due to shifting of database or anyother thing.

I searched in the internet for a day and still no solution to this.

Why this happens and anyone can suggest it. Whether i need to add other gems. I am using sql5.5 and also reinstalled it. I removed all the dependent files while uninstalling.

Database.yml file : contains all the required things

```
            development:
              adapter: mysql2
              database: User_development
              encoding: utf8
              reconnect: false 
              host: 127.0.0.1  
              username: root
              password:
              pool: 5
              timeout: 5000

            test:
              adapter: mysql2
              database: User_test
              encoding: utf8
              reconnect: false 
              host: localhost 
              username: root
              password:
              pool: 5
              timeout: 5000
              socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


            production:
              adapter: mysql2
              database: User_production
              encoding: utf8
              reconnect: false 
              host: localhost 
              username: root
              password:
              pool: 5
              timeout: 5000
              socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

            GEM FILE: it contains all the required  gems

            source 'https://rubygems.org'

              gem 'rails', '3.2.22'
              gem 'rails_12factor'
              gem 'test-unit'
              gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
              gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
              gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
              gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'  
              gem 'yaml_db'
              gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.0'

              group :development, :test do
                 #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'


                gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
                 gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
              end

              group :development do
                gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
              end


              group :assets do
                gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
                gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
                gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
              end

              gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

              group :test do
                gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
                gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
                gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
                gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
              end

              group :production do
                gem 'pg', '0.12.1'
              end
```

Do I have to do anything else after the migration?

Comment: Do you have `mysql2` gem in `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes I included mysql2 in my gemfile

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after that ?

Comment: I did it.  Here is what in my gemfile and database.yml file

Comment: I would suggest to read `https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.5.2` it worked form if I followed each step

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the issue. Please follow below
add following line in your envrionment.rb file.
`require File.expand_path('../initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter', __FILE__)`

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me in addition to having the file around. Seems to be an issue with a fairly modern rspec setup and Rails 3.2. For some reason the load order is completely different under RSpec there and breaks the Rails stack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. gem install mysql adapter is the problem here u need to uninstall it and remove a file it created in config/initializers/abstract.rb file